# C# vs C++ 32 bit vs 64 bit compiler performance

Tags: c#, performance, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

I am writing a performance-critical program and I hesitate between C# which I am more familiar with or Visual C++. I've run several benchmark tests specific to the kind of operations I will need to use and the results puzzle me:
(The reference for these tests is C++ Win32 build)

**By reference**
C# 32 : 50% slower,
C# 64 : 4% slower

**By value**
C# 32 : 21% slower,
C# 64 : 1% faster

Building for x64 in Visual C++ is about 20-30 slower than building as Win32 with the same compiler options (optimized for speed).

I am amazed at how the 64-bit C# compiler performs compared to its 32-bit counterpart. Why does the same not happen in Visual C++? Is the 64-bit compiler not optimized for 64-bit?

In the benchmark I pass an object which has several imbricated structs as attributes.
The benchmark consists of a series of 50 imbricated if statements which test booleans contained in the structs. There are also no long types involved.
I can post the code if needed, but I thought maybe this is just something I don't know about the compilers.

**Edit**: C++ Win32 is compiled with /MT for the best performance. I've tried compiling x64 with /MD and the performance is only about 6 times slower. *I also remember that when I ran the same test on a similar piece of code a year ago in VS2013, the x64 and Win32 builds performed the same as I remember...*

Comment: Firstly, using a 64 bit compiler doesn't mean compiling **for** 64 bit computers. Secondly, what are you passing "by value" in C#? You say you pass an object which contains structures, but is this a value type or reference type?

Comment: I meant that the target platform is 64-bit, sorry. The object is of reference type.

Comment: Well that's hardly a fair comparison, as "by value" in C# with a reference type is not by value at all.

Comment: True, but the main point is why is the x64 build in C++ much slower than Win32.

Comment: it depends on a lot of things, but I'd imagine that in 32 bit mode it's using 32 bit bools, so it can pass 2 along the address bus or something like that

Comment: It is challenging to make a synthetic compiler test that has any bearing on real-world scenarios, and comparing C# directly to C++ for the same task is largely irrelevant. C# code is architecture neutral, JIT-based, and all about productivity. C++ development is architecture-specific, intended for high levels of control and low-level performance-sensitive development, and is compiled once to native code. Badly written C++ code is going to perform badly. Extremely well written C# is not going to match C++ performance for sufficiently complicated tasks.

Comment: I understand most of this, however the task is extremely simple I think, as it involves only basic arithmetic on bools and ints (mostly) on a large scale within a struct. I use the same struct in C# as in C++, one with a generic, the other with  a template. The point for me was comparing two ways of getting the same end result. Interesting point about C++ being architecture-specific. I've googled and found a lot of ways to optimize C++ based on architecture, however I still can't understand why the x64 build performs so poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I actually made the silly mistake of believing bool is initialized to false by default in C++, as it is it C#...

In C++, the 32-bit application now has the same performance as the 64-bit one, even though both are currently much worse than in C#; there is probably something bad in my code!

Comment: First, you said "C# 32 : 50% slower", now you are saying "both are currently much worse than in C#". So which one is faster? Also, without seeing the code for both cases, any comparisons are kind of silly.